# LTC6101 current measurement does not work

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, current-measurement, high-voltage

Thanks for answering my previous question.

The board is facing short circuit problem on 100 V nets. And I'm doubting the attached circuit. Do you think connecting U26 R58 is right?

I read U26's (P-MOSFET) pin 1 (gate) & pin 2 (source) as 52 Ω.
[image: Current measurement circuit]

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a link to your "previous question", so that people reading this question do not need to go searching.

Comment: 52 ohm as Rgs let me assume U26 is dead. Your circuit is close to the recommended application and looks OK, but there may come up some oscillations, which escalate. I would try 100 nF between pin 5 and 7 of IC4 and a resistor of some kohm in the drain path of U26.